# Отдельные символы в консоли

Tags: c, unicode, символы

Как выводить такие символы в консоль как [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. латинские символы с верхним подчеркиванием или с двойным верхним подчеркиванием в консоль на языке си.
Если в символах в acsii их нет.

Comment: В две строки :)

Comment: А в unicode они есть?

Comment: Выводить как юникод символы `v̿`?